# How to avoid scrolling in RichTextBox control

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I want to set the textbox's height for example to 50, and no more, and will not be scrolling in the textbox.

I tried to set the property `ScrollBars` to `RichTextBoxScrollBars.None` and it does not help, indeed did not display the scroll bar, but there is a scrolling.

Comment: So you want to be able to add text past the visible area of the text box, but not to be able to get to it?

Comment: No. not be possible to insert text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions if selecting the text is not important.

One option is to disable the rich text box, it will prevent scrolling and selecting text, but it will also grey out the text and background.

```
this.richTextBox2.Enabled = false;
```

The second option is this class that will prevent the cursor from moving, thus preventing scrolling selecting text, but does not grey out the background.

```
class RichTextBoxEx : RichTextBox
{
    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.SelectionStart != 0)
        {
            this.SelectionStart = 0;
            this.SelectionLength = 0;
        }
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
    }
}
```

I tested this with .Net 2.0